# "About this mac -> Storage" show different values than "Macintosh HD"

Tags: hard-drive, macos, storage

I attached images to better illustrate the problem

Notice how the total of all the file folders in the Macintosh HD pic is approximately 150GB

--however--

"About This Mac -> Storage" shows only 24GB free of 250GB

[image]

vs

[image]

I believe I've reindexed the HD by preforming the following steps:

1. System Preferences -> Spotlight
2. Click Privacy tab
3. Drag Macintosh HD to dropbox and click ok
4. Remove Macintosh HD from list with "-" button
5. Restart the mac

The reason I'm trying to figure this out as I'm trying find the files taking up the most space in order to free up space on the mac.

Comment: Unfortunately El Capitan does not have the "Manage" option in the About this Mac > Storage that would allow you to see and delete large files.

Comment: You might be interested in app called OmniDiskSweeper that could help you https://www.omnigroup.com/more/

Answer (score 0):

These show ***absolute*** TOTAL space, not ***usable*** space. For instance, you’ll have some space used for swapping. Clearly, swap is part of the total amount, but not available for use for general storage. Also, depending on how the disk is partitioned that will affect space. For a more practical display of space, try:

```
df -h
```

For instance, those tools show my disk space as 4GB in total, but that’s not all available for my use: `df -h` shows it as 3.6 GB.